# Asynchronous, non-blocking background execution in Ruby script

Tags: ruby

I am trying to execute some code in a non-blocking way.

In my real scenario, this would be an expensive SQL query in a Ruby on Rails app, however, as a test for replicating the scenario, I made this Ruby script:

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'async'

puts 'hello'

Async do
  sleep 2
  puts 'hi'
end

puts 'there'
```

My expectation would be to see:

```
hello
there
```

immediately. However, what I actually get, is:

```
hello
hi
there
```

after two seconds.

I don't care about the return value of the async call — I just want to execute some code in the background and exit immediately.

Is there a way to do this in Ruby 3?

Comment: _"execute some code in the background and exit immediately"_ – if you exit (as in terminate the Ruby script / process), your code won't run anymore. For background tasks in Rails, have a look at [Active Job](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) or [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You easily do this using a thread.

```rb
puts 'hello'

# Async == Thread
Thread.new do
  sleep 2
  puts 'hi'
end

puts 'there'
``
```

Comment: Note that without [`join`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Thread.html#method-i-join) the sub thread will be killed as soon as the main thread printed "there". It doesn't keep running on its own.